# Convolutional auto-encoder error - 'RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.ByteTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same'

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, autoencoder

For below model I received error 'Expected stride to be a single value integer or list'. I used suggested answer from https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/expected-stride-to-be-a-single-integer-value-or-a-list/17612/2
 and added

```
img.unsqueeze_(0)
```

I now receive error :

```
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.ByteTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

For below code I three sample images and attempt to learn a representation of them using an auto-encoder :

```
%reset -f

import torch.utils.data as data_utils
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import metrics
import datetime
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
from ast import literal_eval
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
import torch
import torch
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
from os import listdir
import cv2
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


number_channels = 3

%matplotlib inline

x = np.arange(10)
m = 1
b = 2
y = x * x
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('1-increasing.jpg')

x = np.arange(10)
m = 0.01
b = 2
y = x * x * x
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('2-increasing.jpg')

x = np.arange(10)
m = 0
b = 2
y = (m*x)+b
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('constant.jpg')

batch_size_value = 2

train_image = []

train_image.append(cv2.imread('1-increasing.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED).reshape(3, 288, 432))
train_image.append(cv2.imread('2-increasing.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED).reshape(3, 288, 432))
train_image.append(cv2.imread('decreasing.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED).reshape(3, 288, 432))
train_image.append(cv2.imread('constant.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED).reshape(3, 288, 432))

data_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(train_image, batch_size=batch_size_value, shuffle=False,drop_last=True)

import torch
import torchvision
from torch import nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.utils import save_image
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
import os

if not os.path.exists('./dc_img'):
    os.mkdir('./dc_img')


def to_img(x):
    x = 0.5 * (x + 1)
    x = x.clamp(0, 1)
    x = x.view(x.size(0), 1, 28, 28)
    return x


num_epochs = 100
# batch_size = 128
batch_size = 2

learning_rate = 1e-3
dataloader = data_loader

class autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, stride=3, padding=1),  # b, 16, 10, 10
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2),  # b, 16, 5, 5
            nn.Conv2d(16, 8, 3, stride=2, padding=1),  # b, 8, 3, 3
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.MaxPool3d(3, stride=1)  # b, 8, 2, 2
        )
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose3d(8, 16, 3, stride=2),  # b, 16, 5, 5
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose3d(16, 8, 5, stride=3, padding=1),  # b, 8, 15, 15
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose3d(8, 1, 2, stride=2, padding=1),  # b, 1, 28, 28
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x


model = autoencoder()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate,
                             weight_decay=1e-5)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for data in dataloader:
        img, _ = data
        img.unsqueeze_(0)
#         img.unsqueeze_(0)
#         print(img)
#         img.unsqueeze_(0)
        img = Variable(img).cuda()
        # ===================forward=====================
        output = model(img)
        loss = criterion(output, img)
        # ===================backward====================
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    # ===================log=================to_img=======
    print('epoch [{}/{}], loss:{:.4f}'
          .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, loss.data[0]))
    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        pic = to_img(output.cpu().data)
        save_image(pic, './dc_img/image_{}.png'.format(epoch))

torch.save(model.state_dict(), './conv_autoencoder.pth')
```

But as stated earlier this results in error :

> ```
> 299     def forward(self, input):
> 300         return F.conv2d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
> ```
>
> --> 301                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
>       302 
>       303
>
> RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.ByteTensor) and weight type
>   (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same

The issue appears to be related to `img.unsqueeze_(0)` ?

How to train the auto-encoder on these images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your image tensor resides in GPU (that happens here `img = Variable(img).cuda()`), while your model is still in RAM. Please remember that you need to explicitly call `cuda()` to send a tensor (or an instance of `nn.Module`) to GPU.

Just change this line:

```
model = autoencoder()
```

To this:

```
model = autoencoder().cuda()
```

Comment: thanks but that change causes error ' RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.ByteTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same '

Comment: I think what you need is [torch.from_numpy](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/torch.html#torch.from_numpy) function to convert np ndarray to tensor first, before using `Variable()`. But you're using pytorch 0.3, admittedly I've never used that version, so can't guarantee anything

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use cuda for training your model. make sure both your model and inputs to your model are shifted to GPU. Shifting only model or only inputs will cause such erros.